# Getting wrong answer for "Geek and New job" problem gfg

Tags: python

```
    #code
testcases=int(input())
while testcases!=0:
    s=input()
    lower,upper,numeric=0,0,0
    
    for i in s:
        if ord(i)>=49 and ord(i)<=57:
            numeric+=1
        elif ord(i)>=65 and ord(i)<=90:
            upper+=1
        
        elif ord(i)>=97 and ord(i)<=122:
            lower+=1
    
    if(upper>=1 and lower>=1 and numeric>=1):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
    testcases-=1
```

The Question is : Given a string i have to Say if the String is a Valid Paswword or not.

For a String to be a valid password following needs to be fullfilled:
1.Atleast one uppercase letter
2.Atleast one lower case letter
3.Atleast one numeric.

if its a valid pasword print "YES" orelse print "NO"

I am not able to figure out why i am getting "wrong answer" on submission in GFG. When i run against custom test cases i get the desired result , but on submission it shows "wrong answer". Can someone please help, what wrong with my code?

I would be able to figure out but the ide of gfg does not tell the reason behind wrong number it just says wrong answer..how will i be able to figure out then?

Constraints:

1<=T<=10^4

1<=|S|<=4*10^5

Sum of S over all tc's does not exceed 4*10^5

Comment: `JohnSmith000`.

Comment: "Getting wrong answer ..." is not a useful title.

Comment: IDE  of GFG says wrong answer . it does not say anything else,, Thats why im not able to figure out the reason

Comment: @ARINDAMMANDAL Can't you figure it out already from the example I gave?

Comment: You are not checking for 0

Comment: @matszwecja Yeah i got it -- i was not considering 0 as numeric..Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking for zero. To avoid this kind of error use the chars, so it is clearer what the code is doing.

The cause of the error is the [antipattern "magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). Programmers should avoid writing numbers directly in the code, because is harder for humans to understand the code, and is prone to error, like this one.

```
testcases = int(input())
while testcases != 0:
    s = input()
    lower, upper, numeric = 0, 0, 0

    for i in s:
        if ord(i) >= ord("0") and ord(i) <= ord("9"):
            numeric += 1
        elif ord(i) >= ord("A") and ord(i) <= ord("Z"):
            upper += 1
        elif ord(i) >= ord("a") and ord(i) <= ord("z"):
            lower += 1

    if upper >= 1 and lower >= 1 and numeric >= 1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
    testcases -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

###### I misread the testcases part and see that you want to test multiple... still leaving this code here for anyone that finds it useful:

You can do a `while True` loop and then `break` the loop when the desired result occurs. This will stop your double `input()` so you don't have to enter the password twice (as you do in your code). Also, if you use `isnumeric(), isupper(), and islower()` it looks cleaner:

```py
while True:
    s=input()
    lower,upper,numeric=0,0,0
    for i in s:
        if i.isnumeric():
            numeric+=1
        elif i.isupper():
            upper+=1        
        elif i.islower():
            lower+=1
    if(upper>=1 and lower>=1 and numeric>=1):
        print("YES")
        break
    else:
        print("NO")
```